# how to count arrays with array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am making a program which draws squares in a square. Every square is defined with x and y which present square's position and with w and h which present square's size. (Square(x, y, w, h)). To create a square I use * in a table defined with main[HEIGHT][WIDTH] and then I print those *.
Now I want to create an array which size is defined with a number of squares I create. Also, I want to define every square I create with a number, because I want to operate with those squares after I add * in array.. For example, if I print square(5, 5, 10, 10) and square (10,5,10,50), the squares colapse. To avoid this problem, I want to delete the first square.

So when I draw square 1, I want 1 in new array. When I draw Square 2, I want 2 in new array. But then I want to remove 1 from array and also all * that were created with square 1.

Please help me because I am stuck at this point of creating my program.

Also I would like to say sorry for my bad english but I hope you understand me.

code:

```
private static final int WIDTH = 20;
private static final int HEIGTH = 20;
static char[][] drawBoard = new char[HEIGTH][WIDTH];


public static void drawSquare(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    for(int i=0; i < drawSquare.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j < drawSquare[i].length; j++){
            drawSquare[0][j]='*';
            drawSquare[HEIGHT-1][j]='*';
            drawSquare[i][0]='*';
            drawSquare[i][WIDTH-1]='*'; 
            for(int k=0; k < h-1; k++) {
                for (int l=0; l<w-1; l++) {
                    if (i != 0 && i != h-1) {
                        drawSquare[k+y][l+x]='o';
                    }       
                    drawSquare[h+y-1][l+x]='=';
                    drawSquare[0+y][l+x]='=';
                    drawSquare[k+y][w+x-1]='|';
                    drawSquare[k+y][0+x]='|';
                    drawSquare[0+y][0+x]='+';
                    drawSquare[h+y-1][w+x-1]='+';
                    drawSquare[0+y][w+x-1]='+';
                    drawSquare[h+y-1][0+x]='+';
                }
            }   
            System.out.print(" "+drawSquare[i][j]);     
        }   
        System.out.println();       
    }   
}
    main method:
    int x=5;
    int y=5;
    int w=5;
    int h=5;
   drawSquare(x,y,w,h);
```

Comment: you only need width or height, as in a square they are the same thing

Comment: Could you show us your code please, so that we can point out where you're going wrong?

Comment: @EdgarBoda I can also create rectangles this way, so I want to keep code in this way. Drawing is not the problem here, my problem is to count all Squares I created and how delete them.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a fifth parameter to `drawSquare`, which indicates whether you're drawing or erasing.  That is, if `erasing` is true, you could write `" "` for each point around the square, instead of all those other characters.  Then you can explicitly call `drawSquare` with `true` for `erasing` whenever you need to.

Comment: I thought of this idea but if I have 3 squares that are overlaying, deleting the middle one with your method will also delete some parts of first and third square. But I want to keep first and third square still there.

Comment: It sounds to me like every cell of your `drawBoard` needs to be a structure that implements a stack of characters, so that when you erase something, you just pop a character off the top of the stack, exposing the one underneath.

Comment: No, not a stack.  Use a `LinkedHashMap`, keyed by which square it is.  That way, you can remove a square from above or below others.

Comment: I don't know how to use LinkedHashMap. Can I solve my problem using a loop which saves my squares as table? As @Gravez said.
But I am also stuck here.

Comment: Just a simple table of characters isn't enough to let you know which character to restore when one square is deleted.  You need some kind of three-dimensional structure, which represents a whole pile of squares.  I guess you could do it with a 3D array, if you were prepared to write empty space at every cell that isn't part of your square, every time you draw a square.  But really, a `LinkedHashMap` would be much simpler.